# putting the { } correclty in if loop of perl script

Tags: matlab, perl, syntax-error

Hi I am trying to translate a code from matlab to perl script. My matlab code is as follows:

```
for i=1:n
if 
  statement
if 
  statement
if 
  statement
else 
  statement

for j=1:1000
if 
  statement
end
end

if 
  statement
else 
  statement
end

end
end
end
end
```

Then I translate into perl as below:

```
for ($i=1;$i<=n;$i++){
if (){
  statement
if {
  statement
if {
  statement
else {
  statement
}
for ($j=1;$j<=1000;$j++){
if {
  statement
   }
}

if {
  statement
}
else {
  statement
}

}
}
}
}
```

But there were syntax errors so I change into like below:

```
for ($i=1;$i<=n;$i++){
if (){
  statement
}
if {
  statement
}
if {
  statement
}
else {
  statement
}
for ($j=1;$j<=1000;$j++){
if {
  statement
   }
}

if {
  statement
}
else {
  statement
}
}
```

Then the code runs well but the answer is different. So, I think I am putting { } in "if loop" of perl incorrectly. Please advise how to translate correctly. Thank you

Comment: Always, always, add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to the beginning of your script

Comment: When you change ```if([cond1]) { if([cond2]) {``` to ```if([cond1]) { ... } if([cond2]) { ... }``` surely the logic of your program might change.

Answer (score 5):

You would have immediately noticed the syntax error if you followed proper indentation.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But i think it's same as my example 1. Or do i miss anything?

Comment: @meemee It is the same as your answer, except that I've pointed out where the syntax error is.  I didn't attempt to *correct* it.